Contract Verification Problem
I'm encountering a perplexing issue while trying to verify my contract through BaseScan. I received a successful verification response from https://api.basescan.org/api as follows:
{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": "z283vufbr46dt2px5xs5ksckbwsx2eh8xpnpsixaeufihhwd5m"
}

However, when I query the API to check the contract's verification status using the endpoint https://api.basescan.org/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${contractAddress}&apikey=${apiKey}, I receive the following response indicating that the contract is not verified:
{
  "status": "0",
  "message": "NOTOK",
  "result": "Contract source code not verified"
}

HERE IS MY CODE THAT RESPOND WITH A FAKE VERIFICATION SUCCESS:
import axios from 'axios';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import solc from 'solc';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { checkVerificationStatus } from './check-contract-verified';
dotenv.config();

const tokenSymbol = 'MTK';
const initialSupply = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1000000", 18);

export const verifyContract = async (contractAddress: string, contractName: string, tokenName: string) => {
  console.log(initialSupply.toString(), 'ddd');

  const apiKey = process.env.BASE_SCAN_API_KEY;
  if (!apiKey) {
    console.error('API Key is missing. Please check your .env file.');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const sourceCode = await fs.readFile('TokenDeployment/src/contracts/Token.sol', 'utf8');
    const abiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder();
    const encodedParams = abiCoder.encode(
      ["string", "string", "uint256"],
      [tokenName, tokenSymbol, initialSupply.toHexString]
    );


    console.log('tokenName: ', tokenName);
    console.log('tokenSymbol: ', tokenSymbol);
    console.log('initialSupply: ', initialSupply.toHexString());
    console.log('contractAddress: ', contractAddress);

    console.log(encodedParams);

    const constructorArguments = encodedParams.slice(2);

    const compilerVersion = solc.version();

    const postData = {
      apikey: apiKey,
      module: 'contract',
      action: 'verifysourcecode',
      contractaddress: contractAddress,
      sourceCode: sourceCode,
      codeformat: 'solidity-single-file',
      contractname: contractName,
      compilerversion: `v${compilerVersion}`, // Ensure version formatting is correct
      optimizationUsed: '1',
      runs: '200',
      constructorArguments: constructorArguments,
      licenseType: '3', // Ensure the license type is correct based on your context
    };

    // console.log("Post Data:", JSON.stringify(postData, null, 2));
    const response = await axios.post('https://api.basescan.org/api', postData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    });
    console.log('Verification response:', response.data);
    if (response.data.status === '1') {
      console.log('Verification successful:', response.data.result);
      await checkVerificationStatus(contractAddress)
    } else {
      console.log('Verification failed:', response.data.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.error('Axios error response:', error.response?.data);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
    }
  }
};

Could you please help clarify why there is a discrepancy between these responses and assist me in resolving this issue?
Thank you for your assistance.
